# python 特定の文字を削除

Tags: python

下記の方法で`lan=`のみを削除できましたが、`lon=`を削除するにはどのように設定すればよろしいでしょうか？

```
print(a.text [4:])

lan= 1.287806 Lon=103.854935
```

Comment: print(a.text [4:])

実行結果: 1.287806  Lon=103.854935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

正規表現を使うのが簡単でしょう。

```
import re

str = "Lat=1.287806 Lon=103.854935"
m = re.search(r"^Lat=([0-9.]+)\s*Lon=([0-9.]+)", str)
if m:
  print(m.group(1)+' '+m.group(2))
```

結果

```
1.287806 103.854935
```

「単に固定文字列を取り除くだけ」と言うことがわかっているなら、`replace`でも良いでしょうが。

```
print(str.replace("Lat=", "").replace("Lon=", ""))
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。下記の方法で実行しましたが、出力データ何も表示されません。

Comment: a=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsm"]/center[1]/a')　　
　print(a.repleace("Lat=","").repleace("Lon=",""))　　print(a.text)

Comment: お手数ですがご確認お願いします。

Comment: 回答中では`a_text`に文字列が入っていることを前提にしています。`a`に対して`replace`メソッドを呼んでも文字列操作にはなりません。

Comment: a_textにしても同じです。Xpathからtextをrepleaceしたいです。

Comment: あなたのコード中には`a_text`は存在しないので、そのコードをそのまま実行しても所望の動作にはならないでしょう。(発生するエラーが違うので「同じ」ではないはずです。)どの部分があなたのコードの何に当たるのか見定めて、最低限必要な書き換えはご自身でおこなってください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。はい！存在しないです。a_textは例であるとわかります。 a=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsm"]/center[1]/a')　print(a.text)にするとLan= 1.287806 Lon=103.854935 結果が表示されます。.repleaceだと表示されないので、.textの配置の問題だと思います。もし分かれば教えていただけますか？

Comment: あたなのコードの中で「文字列」を表しているのは何でしょうか?`print(a.text[4:])`で部分文字列が表示できるのは`a.text`が文字列を表しているからだと言うことはご理解いただいていますか?`replace`は文字列に適用しないと回答中のような動作にはなりません。

Comment: はい！.textがあるとデータが表示されるのがわかります。ただreplaceして、テキスで出力したいです。XpathからTextを取得しています。それが関係しているではないでしょうか？

Comment: https://cellphonetrackers.org/gsm/gsm-tracker.phpのサイトでTrack itを押すとLat=60.208511 Lon=24.752884が表示されます。　Xpathで取得できましたがただLat=とLon=をうまく削除できないです

Comment: 関係しているのは「どれが文字列か」だけです。「文字列」に対して`replace`を呼び出してください。`a`は文字列ではありません。

Comment: いつも迅速な返事ありがとうございます。　はい！aはただの変数です

Comment: 「ただの変数」かどうかは関係ありません。「ただの変数」でもその中身が文字列であれば`replace`はどうさします。今は`a`の中身は文字列ではありません。もう一度聞きます、**あなたのコードの中でどれが文字列ですか？**

Comment: 私のコードには文字列ありません。例えばXpathからテキス取得します。
 casa3=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsm"]/center[1]/a')　　print(casa3.text [4:] [0:-4])　今の実行結果：1.287806 Lon=103.85になります。　Lan= とLon＝を削除か置換したいだけです。

Comment: ***私のコードには文字列ありません。*** 私のコメントを全部読んでいただいているのでしょうか…。「`print(a.text[4:])`で部分文字列が表示できるのは`a.text`が文字列を表しているからだと言うことはご理解いただいていますか?」

Comment: 失礼いたしました。文字列表していることがわかりました。でその文字列をreplaceするにはどのようにすれば良いですか？.textから.replaceにすると実行結果が表示されません。色々な質問してしまい申し訳ないです。最近pytonを学びはじました。

Comment: `a.text`が文字列を表しているのですよね?あなたのコードでは`a.text[4:]`と書くと文字列から部分文字列を取る操作ができたのですよね?「.textから.replaceにすると実行結果が表示されません。」では何がどうなっているのかよくわかりません。

Comment: a.text.replaceでできました。色々とありがとうございました。

Comment: @sakaolo さん、長々とお付き合いありがとうございました。最初`a_text`で動作確認した後、投稿する際にどのように修正すべきか迷ったんですが、結局そのままにしてしまいました。このレベルの書き換えが自分でできないと、今後ネットで情報を集めるのにも苦労するかと思い、敢えてそのままにさせていただいたのですが、もう少しこんな書き方にすればもっと早く気が付けた、なんてことがあればご指摘ください。今後もまだしばらくは疑問に思うことが多々出るかと思いますが、臆せずにこのサイトの方も利用してください。