# python 特定のページを開く

Tags: python

別のページから取得したテキストをdriver.getを使って特定ウェブサイトを開きたいです。

```
a=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsm"]/center[1]/a') 
print(a.text.replace("Lat=", "").replace("Lon=", "").replace(" ",","))
```

別のページから取得した情報：`a=60.208511,24.752884`

情報を取得後、下記の方法で特定のページを開きたいですが、実行しても何も開きません。
変数を使って開く場合、どのように設定すれば良いでしょうか。

```
link='https://www.google.com/maps/search/'+a
print(link)
```

実行結果：なし

```
driver.get(link)
```

`link='https://www.google.com/maps/search/'`のみで実行するとウェブサイトが開きます。
変数`a`を追加すると開きません。

実行結果：`https://www.google.com/maps/search/`

お手数ですが、ご教授願いします。

Comment: driver.get='（https://www.google.com/maps/search/"+a）でも開きませんでした。

Comment: 引用符が左右でマッチしていません。一重`'`で始めたら`'`で終わらないと、あるいは二重`"`で終わるなら同じ`"`で始まっていないといけません。とりあえず一重引用符に統一して`link='https://www.google.com/maps/search/'+a`とするとどうなりますか?

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。一重引用符統一してもページは開きません。

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます。まずその点はご質問内容を修正していただいた方が良いでしょう。また、`print(a)`の部分の表示結果はなんですか？`driver.get('https://www.google.com/')`という単純な場合には「ページが開く」状態になっていますか？そこら辺もご質問中に追記してください。回答者にとって必要となる情報を出来るだけ読みやすく質問中に含めておくことで、より多くの人に回答を考えてもらえることにつながります。ご自身の質問は「編集」から編集できるようになります。

Comment: こちらこそありがとうございます。編集しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

間に説明が入ってしまっているので少しわかりにくいのですが、現在のコードはこのような状態というところでよろしいでしょうか?

```
a=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsm"]/center[1]/a') 
print(a.text.replace("Lat=", "").replace("Lon=", "").replace(" ",","))
# (1)->60.208511,24.752884
link='https://www.google.com/maps/search/'+a
print(link)
# (2)(何も表示されない)
driver.get(link)
```

(2)の`print`文の結果が表示されていないのであれば、その前の行

```
link='https://www.google.com/maps/search/'+a
```

でエラーが発生しているので、`print`文が実行されていない、と推定できます。

---

[別質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/59338/13972)のコメント中で「`a.text`は文字列だが、`a`は文字列ではない」というのを確認していただいたのを覚えておいででしょうか。

1つ目の`print`文は、`a.text.replace("Lat=", "").replace("Lon=", "").replace(" ",",")`という式の **計算結果(文字列)を表示しているだけ** であり、`a`の中身を書き換えるものではありません。従って **`a`は文字列ではない** ままです。

文字列(`'https://www.google.com/maps/search/'`)と文字列ではないもの(`a`)を`+`で結合しようとしているのが、エラーの原因と考えられます。

---

上記の **計算結果** を表示するだけで捨ててしまわずに、何かの変数にでも入れて利用すれば良いでしょう。

```
a=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsm"]/center[1]/a') 
coord = a.text.replace("Lat=", "").replace("Lon=", "").replace(" ",",")
print(coord) # (1)
link='https://www.google.com/maps/search/'+coord
print(link)  # (2)
driver.get(link)
```

少なくともこれで、上記のエラーは解消されるので、(1)(2)とも`print`文の結果が表示されるはずで、その結果`link`の値が所望のものになっていれば、そのページが開くはずです。お試しください。